# How to display score on Pygame?

Tags: python, pygame

I'm a new programmer working on a memory game for my computer science summative.The game goes like this: the computer displays random boxes at random positions and then the user has to guess where the boxes are and click on it.

I'm basically done, except right now I'm trying to create like 5 different levels that range in level of difficulty. eg level 1 will display like 2 boxes and level 2 will display like 5, etc. And then if the user gets through all levels they can play again. I know its a lot but I really want to get an A on this.

But right now I'm stuck because it doesnt really work until I try to close the window, and even then it only goes halfway. I'm thinking its how I defined the functions but I'm not to certain. 
Any help would be appreciated.

```
import pygame , sys
import random
import time

size=[500,500]
pygame.init()
screen=pygame.display.set_mode(size)


# Colours
LIME = (0,255,0) 
RED = (255, 0, 0)
BLACK = (0,0,0)
PINK = (255,102,178)
SALMON = (255,192,203)
WHITE = (255,255,255)
LIGHT_PINK = (255, 181, 197)
SKY_BLUE = (176, 226, 255)
screen.fill(BLACK)

# Width and Height of game box
width=50
height=50



# Margin between each cell
margin = 5

rows = 20
columns = 20


# Set title of screen
pygame.display.set_caption("Spatial Recall")

# Used to manage how fast the screen updates
clock=pygame.time.Clock()


coord=[]

# Create a 2 dimensional array. A two dimesional
# array is simply a list of lists.
def resetGrid():
    grid = []
    for row in range(rows):
        # Add an empty array that will hold each cell
        # in this row
        grid.append([])
        for column in range(columns):
            grid[row].append(0) # Append a cell  
    return grid

def displayAllPink(pygame):
    for row in range(rows):
        for column in range(columns):
            color = LIGHT_PINK
            pygame.draw.rect(screen,color,[(margin+width)*column + margin,(margin+height)*row+margin,width,height])
            pygame.display.flip()      

def displayOtherColor(pygame,grid):
    coord = []
    for i in range(random.randint(2,5)):
        x = random.randint(2, rows-1)
        y = random.randint(2, columns-1)                
        color = LIME    
        pygame.draw.rect(screen,color,[(margin+width)*y + margin,(margin+height)*x+margin,width,height])
        coord.append((x,y))  
        grid[x][y] = 1
        pygame.display.flip() 
    time.sleep(1)
    return coord

def runGame(gameCount,coord,pygame,grid):
    pygame.event.clear()
    pygame.display.set_caption("Spatial Recall: Level "+ str(gameCount))
    pygame.time.set_timer(pygame.USEREVENT,1000)
    time = 0
    #clock.tick( 
            # -------- Main Program Loop -----------
    #Loop until the user clicks the close button.
    done = False
    while done==False:    
        event = pygame.event.wait() # User did something
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT: # If user clicked close
            done=True # Flag that we are done so we exit this loop
            pygame.event.clear()
            print "Game ",gameCount, "ends"
        elif event.type == pygame.USEREVENT:
            time = time + 1
            pygame.display.set_caption("Spatial Recall: Level "+ str(gameCount) + " Time: "+ str(time))
            if time == 100:
                done = True
                pygame.display.set_caption("Time out, moving to next level")
                pygame.event.clear()
                return False
        elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            # User clicks the mouse. Get the position
            pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
            # Change the x/y screen coordinates to grid coordinates
            column=pos[0] // (width+margin)
            row=pos[1] // (height+margin)
            if (row,column) in coord:
                print coord
                coord.remove((row,column))
                print coord
                color = LIME
                pygame.draw.rect(screen,color,[(margin+width)*column + margin,(margin+height)*row+margin,width,height])
                if coord == []:
                    done=True 
                    pygame.display.set_caption("Time out, moving to next level")
                    pygame.event.clear()
                    return True
            else:
                color = RED
                pygame.draw.rect(screen,color,[(margin+width)*column + margin,(margin+height)*row+margin,width,height])
            pygame.display.flip() 


def startTheGame(gameCount):
    grid = resetGrid()
    displayAllPink(pygame)
    coord = displayOtherColor(pygame,grid)
    displayAllPink(pygame)
    runGame(gameCount,coord,pygame,grid)

for i in range(2):
    startTheGame(i+1)
pygame.quit ()
```

Comment: Try to clarify *how* it doesn't work and see if you can narrow it down to a more specific question and a smaller chunk of code.

Comment: @dokkaebi. I have tried and I think the problem lies with how I defined the functions. But I don't know why, and thats where I'm stuck.

Comment: write less code before debugging and, check what you write is working as expected before writing more.

Answer (score 2):

the main problem why it is not working at the moment is:

- your globals `rows` and `columns` are set to 20 but your board has only 9 fields, this is why **most** randomly selected `coords` are off the board

then, you do not control that the same `coord` is chosen 2 times.

in general, I would advise choosing better names, especially for `displayOtherColor` which assembles your target coordinates for each level.

for your question how to display score, I would propose setting it as caption, as you are already doing with the running time.